# How do I use modules in other files?

Tags: typescript

I'm struggling with TypeScript modules in other files. Let me explain...

I have a file **ModuleOne.ts** with:

```
module Messages {
    export var TestAlert: string = "It works!";
}
```

then in my **app.ts**, I have:

```
/// <reference path="Scripts/typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="ModuleOne.ts" />
declare var $;

$(function () {
    alert(Messages.TestAlert);
});
```

It compiles fine, but in console, I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: Messages is not defined". If I move Messages module from ModuleOne.ts to app.ts, everything works fine. How do I use Messages module from ModuleOne.ts file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common cause for this is that you haven't included both files in your page:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

This will error as app.js relies on ModuleOne.js - so you need to add a reference to that too.

```
<script src="ModuleOne.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Alternatively you can compile your TypeScript using the --out flag to generate a single JavaScript file for your entire program.

```
tsc --out final.js app.ts
```

The compiler will walk all your dependencies for you, so you only need to specify your top level file.